# What should I write on right of the operator?

Tags: c#, func

I am trying to use Func<> to square the items of a list and return a list of squared items. What should I write on the right of the operator?
Should I write a foreach loop to traverse the items in my list? I am beginner. Really confused.

```
List<int> myintList = new List<int> { 1, 4, 5, 6 };

Func<List<int>, List<int>> SquareList = (m) =>
```

Comment: Are you trying to write a function object that squares the list or actually square the list/ return a new squared list?

Comment: 2nd option you said. It will return squared list also...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your lambda expression, `m` is a `List<int>`. You need to return another `List<int>` with an operation applied to each of the original values.

You can use LINQ's [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) to do that, and [`ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the result to a `List<T>`. This is the 'functional' approach, which is cleaner than the alternative as it focuses more on the 'what' rather than the 'how'.

```
m => m.Select(x => x * x).ToList();
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gBC6e2) for a demo. For comparison, the imperative alternative might be written like this:

```
Func<List<int>, List<int>> SquareListImperative = source => 
{
    var results = new List<int>();

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        results.Add(item * item);                           
    }

    return results;
};
```

Comment: Sorry I corrected it. I meant I want to square the input list items and return this.

Comment: @Lyrk ok, will remove that part of the answer.

Comment: You selected list items with LINQ I think. Can't I use foreach loop here somewhere to traverse instead of "Select"?

Comment: I would argue that Linq or "functional" way is better with less room for bugs in your code.

Comment: @Lyrk I'd agree with Janus that LINQ is a much cleaner route - it abstracts away the *how* and leaves you with a clean picture of *what* you're trying to do. I'll add the imperative option, however.

Comment: @Lyrk in which case you could replace `x => x * x` with any method or function that has the signature  `int -> int`.

Comment: @CharlesMager thank you so much. It is much clearer for me now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner you should read up on [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx). It will make your life 100x easier and more fun.

```
List<int> myintList = new List<int> { 1, 4, 5, 6 };

var squareList = myintList.Select(i => Math.Sqrt(i));
```

Comment: Sorry I meant square of numbers. My bad.

Comment: No worries, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
Func<List<int>, List<int>> SquareList = (m) => m.Select(val => val * val).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

so many ways to achieve.. points to consider is the volume of data to drive right choice

```
var sqlst = myintList.ConvertAll<int>(t => t * t);
```

still for some reason if you need Func an other approach..

```
List<int> myintList = new List<int> { 1, 4, 5, 6 };
Func<List<int>, List<int>> SquareList = (m) =>
{
 return m.ConvertAll(x => x * x);
};
var tt = SquareList(myintList);
```